# Lookig for a specific image linked to on SO

Tags: discussion, fun, images, editor

Somewhere on SO, someone linked to a joke image showing the learning curve for 6 editors. The most memorable part of it (to me) was the fact that the Emacs (or vim?) chart was shown as a spiral (no offense intended to the respective users). Can someone point me in the direction of that answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://images.google.com/images?q=editor+learning+curve

Comment: Sorry to ask, i just couldn't find it for the life of me :)

Answer (score 2):

This looks like the original post:
http://blogs.msdn.com/steverowe/archive/2004/11/17/code-editor-learning-curves.aspx

It's the same image that Jeff and Roger linked to.